# istio send custom dynamic header to application by either using uuid or refer value from another already exiting header

Tags: kubernetes, http-headers, amazon-eks, istio

Is there way in istio to set a custom request header (x-custom-header) with value as dynamic value (uuid) or setting value of the custom header from an already existing header?

I am using gateway + virtualservice + envoy(sidecar)

Example configuration options in nginx =
proxy_set_header x-custom-header $connection:$connection_requests;

I tried below snippet in my virtual service and got literal value "{{ uuid }}" forwarded to my application.

`  http:

- headers:
  request:
  set:
  x-custom-header: '{{ uuid() }}'

  match:

  - uri:
    prefix: /`

Comment: are you trying get x request id value in custom header

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by using following snippet in virtual service

```
   http:
  - headers:
      request:
        set:
          x-custom-header: '%REQ(x-request-id)%'
```